# Django filter queryset on list of "lists"

Tags: django, django-models, django-database

Excuse the phrasing of the title, perhaps it's not the correct way of saying it but I can't come up with a better one.

I have a model called People, and through some means of identifying a bunch of people I want to fetch from the database by knowing their Town, Street, and House, and then query the database for them.

```
class People(models.Model):
    town = models.ForeignKey(Town, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    street = models.ForeignKey(Street, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    house = models.ForeignKey(House, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
```

I could fetch them one by one as below using `People.objects.get(...)`, however when I need to access many it puts a lag on due to the opening and closing of db connections.

```
result = People.objects.get(town_id=tid, street_id=sid, house_id=hid)
```

If I had a list of queries as given below, representing `tid` `sid` and `hid`, could I somehow do this all in one single database transaction? This list could easily grow to be 1000 entries or more.

```
queries = [
    [1, 1, 1]
    [1, 1, 2]
    [2, 1, 1]
    [5, 9, 1]
    [13, 40, 2]
]
```

Comment: Use the [`in` lookup](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/models/querysets/#in) to filter your queryset. Note I'm not sure if you need the exact combinations of tid, sid and hid or a mix of them is also allowed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you need to query for the exact combinations, you would need to first annotate your queryset to construct a concatenation of the three ids:

```
from django.db.models.functions import Cast, Concat
from django.db.models import CharField, Value

queries = [",".join(elem) for elem in queries]
People.objects.annotate(address=Concat(
        Cast('town_id', output_field=CharField()), Value(','),
        Cast('street_id', output_field=CharField()), Value(','),
        Cast('house_id', output_field=CharField()
    )).filter(address__in=queries)
```